# Does the metal construct summoned from Summon Construct also cause fire damage when using Slam?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

The Summoned Construct's Heated Body ability is the same wording as the Remorhaz' (though it does less damage).

Construct Spirit:

> Heated Body (Metal Only). A creature that touches the construct or hits it with a melee attack while within 5 feet of it takes 1d10 fire damage.

Remorhaz:

> Heated Body. A creature that touches the remorhaz or hits it with a melee attack while within 5 feet of it takes 10 (3d6) fire damage.

but unlike the Remorhaz' Bite, the construct's description does not have a clause that it also deals additional (fire) damage on a hit with its Slam.

Construct

> Slam. Melee Weapon Attack: your spell attack modifier to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 1d8 + 4 + the spell's level bludgeoning damage.

Remorhaz

> Bite. Melee Weapon Attack: +11 to hit, reach 10 ft., one target. Hit: 40 (6d10 + 7) piercing damage plus 10 (3d6) fire damage. If the target is a creature, it is grappled (escape DC 17). Until this grapple ends, the target is restrained, and the remorhaz can't bite another target.

**Does a creature count as touching the construct (and get fire damage) if they are hit by its slam attack?**

---

Info on the Summoned Construct is from *Tasha's Cauldron of everything*. Info on Rhemoraz is from *Monster Manual*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### No.

If the construct hits a creature, it's the construct the one touching the creature and not the other way around. That creature is *being touched* by the construct, or more precisely for the game terminology we should say that the creature is hit by the construct with a melee attack.

The only rule we have on this is what's stated in the construct stat block. The rhemoraz having a similar trait to the construct does not entail that the rhemoraz bite action's extra damage also applies in a similar way to the construct slam action.

We could otherwise rely on the english difference between *to touch sb/sth* and *to be touched by sb/sth*.